# ASP MVC 3 - Localization with LocalizationDisplayNameAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, localization

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong in this code:

```
    public class LocalizationDisplayNameAttribute : DisplayNameAttribute
    {


    public LocalizationDisplayNameAttribute(string resourceKey)
    {
        ResourceKey = resourceKey;
    }


    public override string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            string displayName = App_GlobalResources.Global.ResourceManager.GetString(ResourceKey);

            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(displayName)
                ? string.Format("[[{0}]]", ResourceKey)
                : displayName;
        }
    }

    private string ResourceKey { get; set; }


}
```

The culture is set to cs. I have two resources: Global.resx and Global.cs.resx, but when I run this application I always get string from Global.resx (it should be Global.cs.resx)

Comment: could you debug your application and check what the thread's culture and ui culture is?

Answer (score 1):

The following works fine for me:

```
public class LocalizationDisplayNameAttribute : DisplayNameAttribute
{
    public LocalizationDisplayNameAttribute(string resourceKey)
    {
        ResourceKey = resourceKey;
    }

    public override string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            string displayName = Global.ResourceManager.GetString(ResourceKey);
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(displayName)
                ? string.Format("[[{0}]]", ResourceKey)
                : displayName;
        }
    }
    private string ResourceKey { get; set; }
}
```

View model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [LocalizationDisplayName("foo")]
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Foo)
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo)
```

Resources:

`~/App_GlobalResources/Global.resx`:

```
foo: foo
```

`~/App_GlobalResources/Global.cs.resx`:

```
foo: localized foo
```

`~/web.config`:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="cs" uiCulture="cs"/>
    ...
</system.web>
```

prints the correct localized value.